# Detect same class inheritance with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, decltype

I'm trying to write a metafunction that checks whether all types passed as a variadic template parameter are distinct. It seems that the most performant way to do this is to inherit from a set of classes and detect, whether there is an error.

The problem is that compilation fails in the following code, while I would expect SFINAE to work.

**Edit.** The question is not "how to write that metafunction" but "how do I catch that double inheritance error and output `false_type` when it happens". AFAIK, it's possible only with SFINAE.

---

```
template <typename T>
struct dummy {};

// error: duplicate base type ‘dummy<int>’ invalid
template <typename T, typename U>
struct fail : dummy<T>, dummy<U> {};

template <typename T>
true_type test(fail<T, T> a = fail<T, T>());

false_type test(...);

int main() {
    cout << decltype(test<int>())::value << endl;
}
```

[Live version here](http://ideone.com/22S50k).

---

**Edit.** Previously I've tried to do this with specialization failure, but it didn't work either with the same compilation error.

```
template <typename T>
struct dummy {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct fail : dummy<T>, dummy<U>, true_type {};

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct test : false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct test<T, typename enable_if<fail<T, T>::value, void>::type> : true_type {};
```

[Live version here.](http://ideone.com/QN0SVE)

Comment: If you want to use only `T` and `U`, you may use `std::is_same<T, U>::value`. if you want a variadic template, it is more complicated.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've edited the question to be more specific. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't catch duplicate inheritance with SFINAE, because it is not one of the listed reasons for deduction to fail under 14.8.2p8 **[temp.deduct]**; equally, it is because the error occurs outside the "immediate context" of template deduction, as it is an error with the *instantiation* of your `struct fail`.

There is however a very similar technique which is suitable for use in your case, which is to detect an *ambiguous conversion* from a derived class to multiple base classes.  Clearly the ambiguous base classes can't be inherited directly from a single derived class, but it works fine to inherit them in a linear chain:

```
C<> A<int>
|  /
C<int> A<char>
|     /
C<char, int> A<int>
|           /
C<int, char, int>
```

Now a conversion from `C<int, char, int>` to `A<int>` will be ambiguous, and as ambiguous conversion *is* listed under 14.8.2p8 we can use SFINAE to detect it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class> struct A {};
template<class... Ts> struct C;
template<> struct C<> {};
template<class T, class... Ts> struct C<T, Ts...>: A<T>, C<Ts...> {};
template<class... Ts> void f(A<Ts>...);
template<class... Ts> std::false_type g(...);
template<class... Ts> decltype(f((A<Ts>(), C<Ts...>())...), std::true_type()) g(int);
template<class... Ts> using distinct = decltype(g<Ts...>(0));

static_assert(distinct<int, char, float>::value, "!!");
static_assert(!distinct<int, char, int>::value, "!!");
```

Comment: ... and sent bug report to Visual Studio team, as this code, obviously, doesn't work there.

Comment: For a non-recursive solution (variadic multiple inheritance), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32017587/567292

Answer (score 4):

#### THE ERROR

> `prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct fail<int, int>’:
>   prog.cpp:23:29:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:9:8: error: duplicate base type ‘dummy<int>’ invalid
>    struct fail : dummy<T>, dummy<U> {};`

As stated in the above diagnostic you cannot explicitly inherit from the same *base* more than once in a  *base-specifier-list*, and since `T` and `U` can possibly be of the same type.. *BOOM*.

---

#### WAIT, HOLD UP; WHAT ABOUT *SFINAE*?

*SFINAE* is only checked in the immediate context of the template itself, error that happens beyond the declaration are **not** suitable to trigger a *SFINAE*.

> `14.8.2p8` **Template argument deduction** `[temp.deduct]`
>
> > If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the substituted arguemts.
> >
> > Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its templat eparameter types can result in a deduction failure.

The ill-formed inheritance does not happen in the immediate context, and the application is ill-formed.

To answer your question explicitly: since inheritance *never* happens in the declaration of a certain function, the ill-formed inheritance itself cannot be caught by *SFINAE*.

Sure, you can ask for the compiler to generate a class that uses *inheritance*, by instantiation it in the function declaration, but the actual (ill-formed) inheritance is not in the *immediate context*.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph that was not stated in your question, the main objective of this post is to answer *Why?*, the implementation is a bonus. Let me write an optimized version for you, just to show that that too is possible. But as said; **Why?** has been answered.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I've explicitly answered your question, an invalid *base-specifier-list* cannot be instantiated and caught using *SFINAE*. You'll need to first check if such inheritance is possible, and if so; either instantiate it, or not.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple `std::is_same<>`? As far as I can see, it directly models the desired behaviour of your class.

So try something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
fail
{
    fail(const T &t, const U &u)
    {
         static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value,"T and U must have a distinct type");
    }
};
```

Or even better, directly use `std::is_same<T,U>` in your code.

**EDIT:** Here is a solution inspired by Jarod42's but which uses only a single class (to make it clearer: this is an answer to the question *how to write a variadic class template which detects whether all given types are distinct*, which seemed to be the desired goal in one of the early versions of the original question):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...Ts> struct are_all_different {};
template <> struct are_all_different<> {static const bool value=true;};
template <typename T> struct are_all_different<T> {static const bool value=true;};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct are_all_different<T1, T2>
{
    static const bool value = !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct are_all_different<T1,T2,Ts...>
{
    static const bool value = are_all_different<T1, T2>::value
                           && are_all_different<T1, Ts...>::value
                           && are_all_different<T2, Ts...>::value;
};

static_assert(are_all_different<char, int, float, long, short>::value, "type should be all different");
static_assert(!are_all_different<char, int, float, char, short>::value, "type should not all different");
```

In the end, for `n` variadic template arguments, this should check for equality of all of the `n*(n+1)/2` combinations.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want a traits to check if all type are differents,
following may help:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...Ts> struct is_in;

template <typename T> struct is_in<T> : std::false_type {};
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Ts>
struct is_in<T1, T2, Ts...> : std::conditional<std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, std::true_type, is_in<T1, Ts...>>::type {};


template <typename ... Ts> struct are_all_different;

template <> struct are_all_different<> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct are_all_different<T> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Ts> struct are_all_different<T1, T2, Ts...> :
    std::conditional<is_in<T1, T2, Ts...>::value, std::false_type, are_all_different<T2, Ts...>>::type {};


static_assert(are_all_different<char, int, float, long, short>::value, "type should be all different");
static_assert(!are_all_different<char, int, float, char, short>::value, "type should not all different");
```

Comment: @Filip Roséen: Man, answers might be either some explanantions which help nothing (see your post) or solutions like this one (which might also include hints or best practices the OP hasn't thought about). I like better the solutions.

Comment: @davidhigh: providing work-arounds without explaining why the particular approach attempted did not work is helpful in the short-term, but not in the long term. *Give a man a fish...*

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: That being said, and while you are free to vote at your own volition, be aware that a number of people consider down-votes as aggressive (for better or worse), and therefore down-voting useful (if incomplete) answers you will be perceived as aggressive. My advice would be to comment on what you perceive as incomplete answers without down-voting; it's up to you to follow it or not :)

Comment: I agree that I don't (fully) answer the OP question and explanation about *immediate context* is missing (but I find it rude to down-vote for that).

Comment: Ok, I agree as well with all of you: having both in your post, the specific answer and the possible improvements is surely the best option. So let's all be friends :-D

Comment: @davidhigh I'm aware about recursive metafunction implementation, but variadic templates were added to speed up metacomputations, and I would like to leave recursion for C++03.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I don't fully understand what you are meaning as you were the one to bring in variadic templates -- an exclusive C++11 feature -- in your original question ... so please explain.

Comment: @davidhigh Nevermind, @FilipRoséen just've explained why the `O(1)` amortized instantiations solution is impossible.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: removing all of your comments renders the whole comment list incoherent if not almost useless. Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really understand what you are trying to achieve, but I can help you with the error

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct fail : dummy<T>, dummy<U> {};

template <typename T>
struct fail<T, T> : dummy<T> {};
```

The error is because when you instantiate `fail` with `T` and `U` the same you basically inherit from the same class twice, which is illegal, so you need to create a specialization to take care of this case.

Comment: OP wants a type traits `are_all_different<Ts...>`

Comment: @Jarod42 I got that, I just don’t understand how all this is going to help him. I would go a whole different way to achieve that. But if he can make this work it doesn’t matter anything else.

Comment: Didn't I say that I know the source of the error? Doesn't it look like an error was added there intentionally?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph where did you say you know the error? To me it doesn’t look like the error was added there intentionally. Maybe I don’t understand your post, in which case I am sorry. Quote from your question: `The problem is that compilation fails in the following code, while I would expect SFINAE to work.`

Comment: @bolov I've fixed the question to be more specific. Sorry.