# Checking if variadic template parameters are unique using fold expressions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Given a variadic template parameter pack, I want to check if all types given to it are unique using an `inline constexpr bool` and [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). I tried something like this:

```
template<class... T>
inline static constexpr bool is_unique = (... && (!is_one_of<T, ...>));
```

Where `is_one_of` is a similar bool that works correctly.
But this line doesn't compile regardless of what I put into is_one_of. Can this even be done using fold expressions, or do I need to use a regular struct for this purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You approach doesn't really work because `is_one_of` needs to be called with a type `T` and all the remaining types **not including `T`**. There's no way of expressing that with a *fold expression* over a single parameter pack. I suggest using specialization instead:

```
template <typename...>
inline constexpr auto is_unique = std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
inline constexpr auto is_unique<T, Rest...> = std::bool_constant<
    (!std::is_same_v<T, Rest> && ...) && is_unique<Rest...>
>{};
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(is_unique<>);
static_assert(is_unique<int>);
static_assert(is_unique<int, float, double>);
static_assert(!is_unique<int, float, double, int>);
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aKth8OAjk2LN4p44)

---

(Thanks to [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) for the simplification that uses a *fold expression*.)

Comment: You're right. I trusted my YouCompleteMe config too much, which surprisingly gave me diags even though it didn't even grok all the c++17 features. Disregard. I'll have to wrap my head around why it works, though because I suspected the given case to fail, from brain-compiling it. Got it; My brain-compiler failed to see `T1, Rest...` as "just the tail", which it of course is. +1

Comment: Could simplify to `T0, Rest...` with the body of `(!is_same_v<T0, Rest> && ...) && is_unique<Rest...>`?

Comment: While the other answer provides a way to do that with fold expression and constexpr bool as I wanted, it comes with a lot of warnings and still requires additional structs which I wanted to do without, so your answer "You can't do it" is more appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**-- EDIT --**

googling I've found an [interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32017587/6022656) that give me inspiration to avoid recursion and to avoid a lot of warnings

So you can define a wrapper of type

```
template <typename>
struct wrapT
 { };
```

and a wrapper for type and integer that inherit from the wrapper for type

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct wrapTI : public wrapT<T>
 { };
```

Next you can define a `foo` class that <s>recursively</s> inherit from `wrapTI`

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public wrapTI<Ts, Is>...
 { };
```

Now `is_unique` can be something like

```
template <typename ... Ts>
static constexpr bool isUnique
   = ( ... && std::is_convertible<foo<std::tuple<Ts...>>, wrapT<Ts>>::value );
```

The point is that `foo<Ts...>` can be converted to `wrapT<T>` only if `foo<Ts...>` inherit one time (and only one time) from `wrapT<T>`, that is if `T` is present one time (and only one time) in `Ts...`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct wrapT
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct wrapTI : public wrapT<T>
 { };

template <typename T,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public wrapTI<Ts, Is>...
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
static constexpr bool isUnique
   = ( ... && std::is_convertible<foo<std::tuple<Ts...>>, wrapT<Ts>>::value );

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( true == isUnique<int, long, long long> );
   static_assert( false == isUnique<int, long, long long, int> );
 }
```

Comment: While your answer provides a way to do that with fold expression and constexpr bool as I wanted, it comes with a lot of warnings and still requires additional structs which I wanted to do without, so the other answer "You can't do it" is more appropriate. But thanks, cool to know that it can be done!

Comment: @Joald - I'm agree with you: the Vittorio's answer is better than mine (and also I find annoying those warnings)

Comment: @Joald - Just for fun... answer modified, recursion avoided and warnings removed :) - But added another wrapper struct :(

Comment: That is really good solution for checking uniqueness that I was looking for. Thanks.