# Is there an std::variant that holds all variants

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking for a class that is like `std::variant` that holds all types instead of one of the types.

So I would like to be able to write:

```
std::all_variant<int, double> av{1, 3.14159};
int i = std::get<int>(av); // i should be 1.
double d = std::get<double>(av); // d should be 3.14159
```

This is basically a `tuple` but guarantees that each type appears only once so you can do `std::get<Type>` instead of `std::get<Index>`.

For context I want to be able to write the following code (so if there is a better way of doing that I would appreciate to know):

```
std::all_variant<int, double> av{1, 3.14159};

template <typename T> // T must be either int or double.
void MyFunc(std::all_variant<int, double> av) {
  std::cout << std::get<T>(av);
}

int main() {
  MyFunc<int>(av); // Should print 1.
  MyFunc<double>(av); // Should print 3.14159.
  MyFunc<std::string>(av); // Error! av doesn't have std::string variant. 
}
```

I'm not sure what this would be called so I'm not sure if this is in the standard library. I guess it wouldn't be to hard to write one but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: How is this better than just using `std::tuple` and accessing the element with `std::get<Type>`? Either way, the best the compiler can do is refuse to compile the code with a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am looking for a class that is like std::variant that holds all types instead of one of the types.

What you are looking for is called [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
std::tuple<int,double> mytup( 1, 2.0 );
std::cout << std::get<int>( mytup ) << "\n"; // prints 1
std::cout << std::get<double>( mytup ) << "\n"; // prints 2
std::cout << std::get<std::string>( mytup ) << "\n"; // compiler error
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ShePio)

As for single type appearance requirement you would get compilation error when you try to use `std::get<type>` instead of index with `std::tuple` with duplicated types. (thanks @max66)

Comment: Maybe you can add that if someone insert two or more times a type in the tuple, the corresponding `std::get<T>(mytup)` gives an error (that, if I understand correctly, is what the OP wants).

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I guess that's what heterogeneous means in the cpp-ref page. I thought you could have multiple entries of the same type in a tuple.

Comment: @BenjyKessler You can have them, it's just that `get<type>()` will refuse to work if `type` appears more than once. `get<index>()` will work regardless.

Comment: @BenjyKessler - You can have multiple entries of the same type in a tuple; but, in that case, `std::get<T>(mytuple)`, where `T` is the type with multiple entries, fail to compile (but you can obtain the values with `std::get<Index>(mytuple)`).

Comment: Oh, that's cool! I assumed get<T> wouldn't work for tuple because of this but I guess the standard library is smart.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Slava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64450607/1782792), you can enforce type-uniqueness in a tuple using for example something like `is_unique` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511516/1782792):

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511516
template <typename...>
inline constexpr auto is_unique = std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
inline constexpr auto is_unique<T, Rest...> = std::bool_constant<
    (!std::is_same_v<T, Rest> && ...) && is_unique<Rest...>
>{};  

// Tuple that only accept unique type parameters
template<typename... Ts>
using uniq_tuple = typename std::enable_if<is_unique<Ts...>, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

int main()
{
    // Compiles
    uniq_tuple<int, float> t1;
    // Fails
    uniq_tuple<int, float, int> t2;
    return 0;
}
```